# MathText markers rendering as dots instead of strings

Tags: python, matplotlib

My code below should have each marker be a two letter string, but is not rendering the mathtext, but instead rendering a dot.  I'm on ubuntu 18.04 using ancaconda 3.7, and I have `dvipng texlive-latex-extra texlive-fonts-recommended` installed. The code produces no errors.  How can I get this code to render the mathtext?  I've printed the marker variable contents and the look like `$aw$` or `$oh$`, etc. So AFAIK, this should work.  I've also tried other string formatting methods like `marker = r'${}$'.format(vowel_match)`.  I get the same dots instead of mathtext.

`vowel_match` is a two letter string, e.g. `ow` or `ae` that gets sourced in this loop.  The exact strings are properly in the legend of the plot.

```
    for point in zip(f1_bark, f2_bark):
        node, indexer = (self.closest_node(point, search_data))
        vowel_match = (df["Vowel"].loc[[indexer]]).values[0]
        marker = f'${vowel_match}$'
        ax_kwargs.plot(point, marker=marker)
```

Here's a graph of what it looks like.

[image: F1F2 Plot that renders dots instead of vowels]

Comment: If you `print(marker)`, do you indeed get those strings?

Comment: Yes. I checked that.  I get strings like this:
`$er$  `

`$uh$ `

`$uw$ `  

`$iy$ `

`$eh$ `

Answer (score 0):

I never got mathtext to work, but there is a matplotlib.text option.  Here's how I fixed the plot

```
    markers = []
    for point in zip(f2_bark, f1_bark):
        node, indexer = (self.closest_node(point, search_data))
        vowel_match = (df["Vowel"].loc[[indexer]]).values[0]
        marker = r"${}$".format(vowel_match)
        x, y = point
        ax_kwargs.text(x, y, marker, fontsize=12)
        markers.append(marker)
        print(marker)

    plot_points = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(f2_bark, f1_bark)))
    ax_kwargs.plot(plot_points, marker='o', c='w', alpha=0, linestyle="None")
```